# How to extract string before cursor position and after the @ character until the first whitespace character using javascript?

Tags: javascript

I am new to programming and I want to extract string from @ character that is before cursor position until I find a whitespace.

what I am trying to do?
consider the string "hello from @us to you"

and the cursor position is at index 12 next to "@" now I want to extract string "us" which is after @ character until whitespace.

This is what I have tried:

```
string1 = value.substr(0, event.target.selectionStart);

string2= string1.slice(string1.lastIndexOf('@') + 1);
string3 = string2.split(' ')[0];
```

But this gives me "" empty string.

how can I get a string "us" could someone help me with this. thanks:

Comment: `string1` won't include anything after `event.target.selectionStart` - which you say is position 12 in `hello from @us to you` which puts the cursor between the `u` and `s`. So it would appear `string` contains `hello from @`. what am I missing?

Comment: hm i mean the string position is after @ character in "@us" then. also string1 extracts string from 0 to u so the string is "hello from @u"

Comment: fixed comment. If you are already using `.lastIndexOf()` - just use that?

Comment: lastIndexOf() is used on string1. so this will give me only string "u" i want to get until whitespace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are very close. Take the *remainder* of the string like below with two approaches. The first operates on the string and the second operates on the array:

```js
const cursorPosition = 6;
const str = "hello from @us to you";
const str1 = str.substring(cursorPosition);
const str2 = str1.substring(str1.lastIndexOf('@')+1).split(' ')[0];
console.log(str2)

//or

const out = str1.split(" ").find(word=>word.includes('@')).substring(1);
console.log(out);
```

Answer (score 0):

similar to what you did:

```
"hello from @us to you".split('@')[1].split(' ')[0]
```